# Physical motions are not smooth despite a high frame rate

Tags: unity

I've been facing this problem since a long time ago. My Unity game is getting 120 FPS, but still, physics-related movements are not as smooth as should be, and the player's movement is totally flickering.

**Information**

I'm working with Unity 2022, on an Android game. But this problem still exists in the editor and PC. All my physics-related scripts are placed in the `FixedUpdate` method, so I guess that high frame rates is not affecting them at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That high FPS that you're seeing is of `Update`, not `FixedUpdate`. You're experiencing something similar to this:

[image]

The red ticks represent frames where `Update` runs, and the blue ticks represent frames where `FixedUpdate` runs. You can have a billion `Update` frames per second, but when `Update` want to access a physics object's position to render to the screen, it must still choose the latest `FixedUpdate` frame available (which is not plenty).

### Altering Rigidbodies

If you can't afford to increase `FixedUpdate`'s frequency (it is costly in terms of computational power), you can "cheat" a little bit by using **interpolation/extrapolation**. Just switch to Interpolate/Extrapolate on any `Rigidbody` that you want to appear smooth.

[image]

**Interpolation** use the `Rigidbody`'s position from the previous TWO physics frames. With two physics frames in hand, the current main frame can choose a smoothed value between that two physics frames, instead of relying entirely on a single physics frame.

**Extrapolation** essentially predicts the future. When a main frame arrives before a physics frame, the main frame can use previous physics frames as data points to "guess" where the physics object could be right now.

You can find out more about interpolation/extrapolation in-game physics with [this fantastic article](https://blog.terresquall.com/2020/08/unity-rigidbodys-interpolate-property/), or [here, where I cropped the red ticks/blue ticks image](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1119684/interpolating-between-fixedupdate-frames.html).

You can also read about the difference between `Update` and `FixedUpdate`, (and even `LateUpdate`) [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/update-vs-fixedupdate-vs-lateupdate-in-unity/).

### Setting the Fixed Timestamp

Note that this method makes a huge impact on the game's performance, but will still solve this problem. To do that, Unity provides an option to alter how frequently the FixedUpdate method is being called, & that is an option named Fixed timestamp, which is available in the Project Settings window > Time. So, in order to fix your problem, you have to set this to a lower value, such as 0.01.

[image: Time window]

> Fixed Timestamp is a framerate-independent interval that dictates when physics calculations and FixedUpdate() events are performed.

More information will be available on [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.2/Documentation/Manual/class-TimeManager.html). Also, I found [this link](https://johnaustin.io/articles/2019/fix-your-unity-timestep) helpful to know more about this topic.